# How can I access to the json datas in my html

Tags: javascript, json, eclipse

I have an eclipse based application, in which I have a welcome page in html.
I made an image slider in html / javascript.

```
    <section...>
    <div class="slideshow-container">
      <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext"></div>
        <img src="img/test.png" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
      </div>
 
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext"></div>
        <img src="img/test1.png" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
      </div>
 
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext"></div>
        <img src="img/test2.png" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
      </div>
 
      <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
    <br>
 
    <!-- The dots/circles -->
    <div style="text-align:center">
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
    </div>
</section>      
 
<script>
        var slideIndex = 1;
        showSlides(slideIndex);
        
        function plusSlides(n) {
          showSlides(slideIndex += n);
        }
        
        function currentSlide(n) {
          showSlides(slideIndex = n);
        }
        
        function showSlides(n) {
          var i;
          var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
          var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
          if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
          if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
          for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
              slides[i].style.display = "none";  
          }
          for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
              dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
          }
          slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
          dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
        }
</script>
```

It works very well ! I am newbie to javascript so I found this code on the internet which turned out to be very effective

It gets worse, when the images I want to display are to be fetched in a json (the json is not responsible for my failure, I also tested with xml)
I tried this:
in my html:

```
<section...>
    <a href="#" id="get-data">Get JSON data</a>
    <div id="show-data"></div>
    <script src="javascript/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
</section>
```

in my example.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var showData = $('#show-data');
 
    $.getJSON('test.json', function (data) {
      console.log(data);
 
      var items = data.items.map(function (item) {
        showData.text(item.value)
        return item.key + ': ' + item.value;
      });
 
      showData.empty();
 
      if (items.length) {
        var content = '<li>' + items.join('</li><li>') + '</li>';
        var list = $('<ul />').html(content);
 
        showData.append(list);
      }
    });
});
```

Under Eclipse I get nothing ...
suddenly I looked for a way to "debug" under chrome and it tells me about "Cross origin requests" concerns.
I looked for what it was for, and on the advice I found launched chrome with the --allow-file-access-from-files option, but nothing helped.
I don't understand the error, as I treat everything locally, my hmtl like my json.
I also tried putting my json on a server, and it was ok.

So I have 2 options:

- someone knows how I can bypass this problem, I cannot use php
- I process the json in java (I am much more comfortable in java and I call this java function via javascript)  is it possible ? I tested but I never enter the java function in question I call this function with its plugin name com.blabla.ClassName.MyFunction but I can't find much on the subject on the net hence the fact that I think maybe this is not the right path to take

Sorry for this long post, I tried to be exhaustive as I tested and did a lot of research!
Thank you for your attention

Comment: You've to turn off the internet security too. The problem after that is, that XHR doesn't work with file protocol, you've to install a local server and use http(s) protocol instead.

Comment: As mentioned by @Teemu you can't use XHR/Ajax with the file protocol. Also many other features won't work while using the file protocol e.g. cookies. Indeed the best case would be to setup a local web server like XAMPP or even a plain Apache.